# How to access variables in other classes

Tags: python, wxpython

In Functions class, I would like to access the variable of the Frame class.

Please tell me if there is any way.

```
class Functions():

    def changeText():
        ...
        ...
        I want to change the 'text' in the Frame class 
        ex )Frame.text.SetFont('change text')
```

GUI element

```
class Frame(wx.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, ....)
    ....
    ....
    self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, .....)
```

Comment: Have you tried making the variables global?

Comment: Not sure about this because of your indentation, is `text` an object attribute (`self.text`) or a class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending an instance of the class to the function:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

def changeText(input):
    input.text = "world"

example = myClass("hello")
changeText(example)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But your example and my question seems to be a bit different .
I want to change the variable in GUI Class(wx.Frame) from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tell your objects what to work on. Out of thin air your `Functions` instance will not know (how should it?) what `Frame` should be. You could make `Frame` a global, but I do not think that is a good idea (it will break if you want to work with more than one frame instance). So you would write:

```
class Functors:
    ...
    def set_text(txt_frame, the_text):
        """txt_frame has to be a :class:`my_txt_frm` instance with ``self.text`` being a ``StaticText`` instance."""
        txt_frame.text.SetLabel(the_text)

class my_txt_frm(wx.Frame): # do not name the derived class Frame to make more clear it is derived!
    def __init__(# ...
        ...
        self.text = wx.StaticText(#...
```

So now comes the interesting part: how to tie the parts together? You have to have something like that somewhere in your code:

```
funct = Functors() # the class which know how to do things on our GUI elements
frm = my_txt_frm(#...
```

Some lines later...

```
funct.set_text(frm, 'thenewtext')
```

So for your app which has the bigger picture it is necessary to keep references to the building blocks to be able to tie them together later.

An orderly way to tie things together is called MVC ([see a great example in the wxPython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController)). Even if you do not want to model your app after this paradigm, you can learn from it how to reason about separation of concerns.